# Where can I find a list of all HQL keywords?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hql, keyword

Where can I find a list of all HQL keywords?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the full Hibernate source download there's a `grammar\hql.g` file, which is the [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/) language definition. You can view the latest version of this file from the official GitHub source repository [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/master/hibernate-core/src/main/antlr/hql.g).

In the `tokens` section you'll find all the tokens, including the keywords (they're the ones defined as strings, e.g. `ALL="all"`).

Answer (score -1):

Try [this](http://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/v3/api/org/hibernate/hql/antlr/HqlTokenTypes.html)...not sure if it's complete or exact, but it may be, as it's a list of HQL tokens.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the BNF for Hibernate 2, I am not sure if this is in the same format as the hql.g files as mentioned above:

http://www.hibernate.org/89.html