# How to select if a row exists in HQL

Tags: sql, hibernate, hql

EDIT: Specifically talking about querying against no table.  Yes I can use exists, but I'd have to do

```
select case when exists (blah) then 1 else 0 end as conditionTrue
from ARealTableReturningMultipleRows
```

---

In T-SQL I can do:

```
select case when exists(blah) then 1 else 0 end as conditionTrue
```

In Oracle I can do:

```
select case when exists(blah) then 1 else 0 end as conditionTrue from DUAL
```

How can I achieve the same thing in HQL?

select count() seems like the second-best alternative, but I don't want to have to process every row in the table if I don't need to.

Comment: take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3672444/where-exists-in-hibernate-hql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer: I believe it's NOT possible.**

My reasoning:

According to [Where can I find a list of all HQL keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586185/where-can-i-find-a-list-of-all-hql-keywords/586324#586324) Hibernate project doesn't publish HQL grammar on their website, it's available in the Hibernate full distribution as a `.g` ANTLR file though.

I don't have much experience with `.g` files from ANTLR, but you can find this in the file (`hibernate-distribution-3.6.1.Final/project/core/src/main/antlr/hql.g`):

```
selectFrom!
        :  (s:selectClause)? (f:fromClause)? {                                                                                                    
                // If there was no FROM clause and this is a filter query, create a from clause.  Otherwise, throw                                
                // an exception because non-filter queries must have a FROM clause.                                                               
                if (#f == null) {                                                                                                                 
                        if (filter) {                                                                                                             
                                #f = #([FROM,"{filter-implied FROM}"]);                                                                           
                        }                                                                                                                         
                        else                                                                                                                      
                                throw new SemanticException("FROM expected (non-filter queries must contain a FROM clause)");                     
                }
```

which clearly states there are some HQL queries having no `FROM` clause, but that's acceptable if that's a filter query. Now again, I am not an expert in HQL/Hibernate, but I believe a filter query is not a full query but something you define using `session.createFilter` (see [How do I turn item ordering HQL into a filter query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1465888/how-do-i-turn-this-hql-into-a-filter-query)), so that makes me think there's no way to omit the `FROM` clause.

Comment: That is great research, thanks a lot!  I'll mark this as the accepted answer for now, with the hopes that someday your answer will no longer be correct. =)

Answer (score 1):

I'm use fake table with one row for example MyDual.

```
    select case when exists(blah) then 1 else 0 end as conditionTrue from MyDual
```

Answer (score 0):

According to http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-expressions it looks like they support both case and exists statements.

Comment: Editted the question to better reflect what I meant.  Sorry to confuse you.

Comment: Ah, I see, looks very similar to a question I asked ages ago that got no answers.  If you get one that works, perhaps you would consider adding it to my question.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/808543/select-constant-in-hibernate